# NHibernate QueryOver to get records which are not older than N days

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, queryover

I have problem while retrieving the records which are not older than 30 days. As today's date is 24 Jun, I would like to select records not beyond than 23rd May.
That is I need all records for the days in between 23rd May and Today.
For that The following query was being implemented

```
session.QueryOver<Property>().WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.DateUpdated).IsBetween(DateTime.Now).And(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30)).List();
```

The Query was running with out any errors but the List was empty.

When seen through visual studio debugger it is saying that

> session.QueryOver().WhereRestrictionOn(x =>
>   x.DateUpdated).IsBetween(DateTime.Now).And(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30)).List()  Expression
>   cannot contain lambda expressions

I wrote the query as per the mock up seen from [here](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try flipping the order of your 'between' clauses- `IsBetween(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30)).And(DateTime.Now)`